# DejaVu Sans Condensed not showing up in Inkscape, despite installed

Tags: fonts, inkscape

My system came with [DejaVu Sans](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/ttf-dejavu-core) and [DejaVu Sans Condensed](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/ttf-dejavu-extra) installed by default.

PROBLEM: [Inkscape](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/inkscape) only shows `DejaVu Sans`.

- Do I have to configure something special in Inkscape?
- Or is `DejaVu Sans Condensed` supposed to be obtained by selecting `DejaVu Sans` and pressing `Toggle bold or normal weight`?
- Or am I misundertanding something about fonts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Inkscape text toolbar](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/SecondaryToolbar) only allows you to select the font family and size, and to toggle bold and italic type, but it [doesn't include any way to select a specific font variant.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/575831)  This has actually been reported as a bug in Inkscape, and should be fixed in the next version (0.49).

In order to select a specific font variant in current versions of Inkscape, you need to open the Text and Font dialog, either via the *Text* menu or by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  This will open a floating dialog window that looks like this:

[image: Inkscape Text and Font dialog screenshot]

Note that this dialog [is currently not dockable,](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/930535) although that should also be fixed in Inkscape 0.49.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your fonts folder and manually remove it - then download a fresh version from [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) (links below as well as some other styles from the family - well worth grabbing.)

[DejaVu Sans](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/DejaVu-Sans)

[DejaVu Sans Mono](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/DejaVu-Sans-Mono)

[DejaVu Serif](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/DejaVu-Serif)

Then try installing these (close inkscape before you install just to be safe)

Comment: Ironically, the website you link to does not contain the `DejaVu Sans Condensed` font... it can be downloaded from elsewhere though.

Comment: yes it does its inside the the deja vu sans family