# How to use font variants within Inkscape

Tags: fonts, inkscape

I'm trying to use Inkscape to design a logo, the issue is that I can't use any variants of one of my fonts, Quicksand Light:

[image: Inkscape]

I know I have the font and its variants installed because GIMP notices and can use them just fine:

[image: GIMP]

How can I get Inkscape to notice and use the variants of fonts?

Comment: Related, maybe even a dupe: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16873/dejavu-sans-condensed-not-showing-up-in-inkscape-despite-installed (but I think this one is better asked).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike in Gimp or other applications there is a strict separation of font family *vs.* font style in SVG, and in Inkscape.

Therefore we will be presented the font family only from selection in the top panel. To change the font style (as they were defined with the installed font) we can either use the default style icons from the tool panel, or adjust it using the *Text > Text an Font...* properties dialog <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>:

[image]

We need to press <kbd>Apply</kbd> after having made changes to take effect.

Comment: Wow! I had no idea you could do this. I just always assumed Inkscape had limited type abilities. This is great!

Comment: Note that there are some [SVG font features](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html) that you can't really access in Inkscape's UI. When in doubt open the XML editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and go rogue!